# Expand/collapse excerpt and content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Setting up a simple WordPress blog, that only contains a single page wich is the blog archive. But i have run in to a problem, i want to have a toggle the excerpt and content show more/show less functionality, så that visitors easy can go trough the posts on the same page without page reloads or beeing sent to the single post page. I know this has been asked here before but none of those examples works for me. Just want a simple show/hide functionality to show the excerpt automatic and when users click show more, the whole post slides open to show complete content, and when they click show less, the post goes back to excerpt. I tried most that is here on stack but nothingworks so now i rolled back to my original files to start over. So this script does nothing right now as you se in the loop-custom file. But this is what i have tried.

Here is my js:

```
    $(function () {
     $('.mainContent').hide();
     $('a.read').click(function () {
         $(this).parent('.excerpt').slideUp('fast');
         $(this).closest('.post').find('.mainContent').slideDown('fast');
  //       $('.mainContent').show();
         return false;
     });
     $('a.read-less').click(function () {
         $(this).parent('.mainContent').slideUp('fast');
         $(this).closest('.post').find('.excerpt').slideDown('fast');
         return false;
     });
 });
```

Here is my index file:

```
    <div id="content">

    <div id="inner-content" class="row">

        <main id="main" class="large-8 medium-8 columns" role="main">           

            <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                <!-- To see additional archive styles, visit the /parts directory -->
                <?php get_template_part( 'parts/loop', 'custom' ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>  

                <?php joints_page_navi(); ?>

            <?php else : ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'parts/content', 'missing' ); ?>

            <?php endif; ?>

        </main> <!-- end #main -->

        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

    </div> <!-- end #inner-content -->

</div> <!-- end #content -->
```

And here is my loop-custom file:

```
<article class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(''); ?> role="article">                 
<header class="article-header">
    <?php get_template_part( 'parts/content', 'byline' ); ?>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

</header> <!-- end article header -->

<section class="entry-content" itemprop="articleBody">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?></a>


    <?php the_excerpt('<button class="tiny">' . __( 'Show more...', 'jointswp' ) . '</button>'); ?>
</section> <!-- end article section -->
```

Comment: you forgot some of your code, the javascript part of it

Comment: where is the .mainContent div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Answer updated after testing in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ldy35wyw/).

```
<div class="post-wrap">
    <h2>The Title</h2>
    <div class="post">
        <div class="excerpt">
            Excerpt goes here
        </div>
        <div class="whole-post">
            Slidey read more content goes here
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="read">Read More</a>
    </div>
</div>


.whole-post {
  display: none;
}

.post {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

a.read {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}



$('a.read').click(function () {
     $(this).siblings('.excerpt').slideToggle(500);
     $(this).siblings('.whole-post').slideToggle(500);
});
```

Further comment asking about changing "read more" button text on click - requires additional line of jQuery, like so:

```
  $('a.read').click(function () {
      $(this).siblings('.whole-post').is(':visible') ? $(this).html('Read More') : $(this).html('Read Less');
      $(this).siblings('.excerpt').slideToggle(500);
      $(this).siblings('.whole-post').slideToggle(500); 
  });
```

jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qrqqt7af/).

Note: The ternary `query ? truthy : falsey ;` syntax is short for `if (query) { truthy } else { falsey } ;`

Comment: This is giving me the same problem @Ryan Gee. I get both the excerpt and the post showing up at the same time with no show/less functionality what so ever.

Comment: Can you provide a link to your jsfiddle. Cant get it to work. The read more button does not to anything ehrn clicked on. I copied your exact code to test.

Comment: @ Ryan Gee Seams to work fine on jsfiddle. But seriously now it displays correctly on my site. But nothing is happening when i push the read more. It still just shows the excerpt. Any idea why? Im a noobie on js and jquery so i dont have no idea why its not working.

Comment: First thing to do would be to check that jQuery is working - try adding: `$('a.read').click(function(){ alert('it is working'); });`. If this creates a popup when you click the link, then the problem is with your classes/jquery selectors. If not, there may be a problem with the way you're including jQuery into the document.

Comment: Has to be something with jQuery. Nothing is happening when i tested with your new snippet and pushed the read more btn. I include jQuery from Google CDN.

Comment: I am working on a local install, can that have something to do with it, or is that not an issue?

Comment: Local install shouldn't be an issue, though I remember when I've used jQuery with Wordpress in the past, there were additional steps I had to take to get the two to play nicely - [this article](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/adding-jquery-scripts-wordpress/?wpcv=b&utm_expid=3606929-93.spVh-aR3SwGklKzL4HJQQg.1&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.uk%2F) may be of use?

Comment: Thank you so much! Now it works perfectly! Just one quick cuestion though, i need the button to display "Show Less.." When the content is opened. To close it down to the excerpt again. Is there a quick way to do this without breaking your script?

Comment: Not if you want to use `slideToggle();` - for that, on click, you'd need to:  Check to see if `.whole-post` is visible. If it is, hide it and set `$('a.read').innerhtml('show more');`. If it's not visible, show it, and set `$('a.read').innerhtml('show less');`.

Comment: Edit: re. changing button text - see bottom of updated answer.

Comment: Thanks man! You are awesome, it works just as i wanted it to:)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-showhide

Comment: This has to be easy tweakable so no plugin. I just have to learn how to do it correct.